# How to reference bi-monthly journal in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, date

The `biblatex` manual states one can't reference a month range (e.g. "Jan-Feb") under `month`, but to use `date` instead for establishing date ranges. The table with example date formats in the manual doesn't include one for a month range. Is it possible to reference a month range under `date`? If so, how? I need to reference a bi-monthly journal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `date = {YYYY-MM/YYYY-MM}` to give a range of month-precision dates, i.e.

```
date = {2017-07/2017-08}
```

An example can be found in Table 3: *Date Specifications* of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), the example there is

> `2002-01/2002-02` 01/2002–02/2002    January 2002–February 2002

Comment: Often it is enough to give only the year of publication. `volume`, `number` and `pages` give enough information to pinpoint the article exactly.

Comment: I was attempting to include `year={YYYY}` along with `date={MM/MM}`. I suppose that never would've worked.

Comment: @RichardSantiago No, if have a `date` field you should not have a `year` or `month` field.